# Submit button text not centering on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css

I'm having one tiny issue on our company website. For some reason, the text inside submit buttons is not centering on iPhones.

URL: http://visioncreativegroup.com.au/
Screenshot: 
[image]

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: How are you styling the button?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code helps:

```
yourButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Give it a try!

Might also be something with the text being bigger than the button

Comment: His problem doesn't seem to be in Native iOS. It seems to be a cross-platform development.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's still the same. :(